# Filter many to many relationship based on child existence and column value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've been searching for a while and couldn't find an answer, here's what I have:

1- ShowCategory (id & title)

```
class ShowCategory extends Model
{
    public function shows()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Show::class, 'category_show');
    }
}
```

2- Show (id, title & active)

```
class Show extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ShowCategory::class, 'category_show');
    }
}
```

So there's a many to many relationship, what I need is retrieving all ShowCategory elements that has at least one Show related to it, and to filter each ShowCategory->shows by show.active, only return shows that are active

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
 $categories = ShowCategory::whereHas('shows', function($query) {
        $query->where('shows.active', '=', true);
    })->get();
```

It only filters ShowCategory that includes shows and if only one of those shows are active, it returns the category with all shows inside, even if others are not active, I need to filter those who are not active.

What should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try it with the relationship
$categories = ShowCategory::get()->shows()->where('shows.active', '=', true)->get();

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: What is shows.active? active is the column and shows is the table right?

Comment: Correct, shows is the table and active is the column, I want only shows with active property equals true to be returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires a combination of `whereHas()` and `with()`. First, `whereHas()` will filter the `ShowCategory` model to those that have an active `Show`, while the `with()` clause will limit the results of the relationship to only return `active` ones:

```
$categories = ShowCategory::whereHas("shows", function($subQuery) {
    $subQuery->where("shows.active", "=", true); // See note
})->with(["shows" => function($subQuery){
    $subQuery->where("shows.active", "=", true);
}])->get();'
```

Note: You should be able to use `active` instead of `shows.active`, but depends on if that column is on multiple tables.

Using this query, you will get a `Collection` of `ShowCategory` models, each with their active `Show` models already loaded and available via `->shows`:

```
foreach($categories AS $category){
    dd($category->shows); // List of `active` Shows
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.

```
$categories = ShowCategory::whereHas('shows', function($query) {
    $query->whereActive(true);
})->get();
```

Comment: This does exactly what my code does, filters ShowCategroy based on show.active, but returns all shows even if they're not active

Comment: is the datatype of active boolean? because from your query and mine should return the correct collection @MahmoudTarek

Answer (score -1):

Try, this can be a possible way to retreive related results.

```
// This will only return ShowCategory which will have active shows.
/* 1: */ \ShowCategory::has('shows.active')->get();

// So, logically this will only have active shows  -__-
$showCategory->shows
```

Laravel allows to extends foreign relation by using this `.` notation as a condition for retreival.

### Update

You should update the `\ShowCategory` model as

```
 public function shows(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Show::class, 'category_show')->where('active', true);
 }
```

Comment: Nope
Call to undefined method App\Show::active()

Comment: Alright, I have updated my answer with an alternate.

Comment: I didn't do that down vote, however I got an answer you may check it. Your latest answer fixes the problem here but makes another problem, if I want to return all shows as administrator, I won't be able to

Comment: Putting `->where('active', true);` breaks the functionality of this relationship. What if they need to get all shows regardless of `active` status?

Comment: Yes but OP's concenr was to manipulate many-to-many relationship. Otherwie I'd suggest to mae  wrapper function over your default `shows` to filter out the `active` one. Anyways, OP's got an answer . problem solved and I understand my mistake :-)